# Maven update doesn't do anything

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, liquibase

I have a jhipster liquibase project and I have generated a changelog with the command mvn liquibase:diff

But when i run mvn liquibase:update nothing happend. Am I doing something wrong ?

20190204170036_changelog.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <changeSet author="User (generated)" id="1549299649735-1">
        <addColumn tableName="booking">
            <column name="price" type="double precision"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="User (generated)" id="1549299649735-2">
        <addColumn tableName="booking">
            <column name="promotional_code_id" type="bigint"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="User (generated)" id="1549299649735-3">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="promotional_code_id" baseTableName="booking" constraintName="FKoyhf3fa96qsyu1wg2yphl17yu" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="promotional_code"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And here is my liquibase configuration in my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://urlofmydatabase:3306/perfectcar</url>
        <defaultSchemaName>perfectcar</defaultSchemaName>
        <username>myusername</username>
        <password>mypassword</password>
        <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.perfectcar.perfectcar.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <logging>info</logging>
        <contexts>prod</contexts>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        [...]
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does your master changelog (at `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml`) reference the diffChangeLogFile `20190204170036_changelog.xml`?

Comment: If i do so i got an error saying that the changelog does not exist

Comment: There's your problem then. The file mentioned in the `<changeLogFile>` tag must exist. If you are just getting started with Liquibase and that diffchangelog file is going to be the starting point for your schema, you could just rename the diffchangelog file and start with that.